# Showing an image

Tags: image, matlab, show

I came to a `matlab` code where it first reads an image and converts it to `double` as follows:

```
I = double(imread(img));
```

After that, it shows the image as follows:

```
imshow(I/max(I(:)))
```

What does that mean? Especially when I removed the `max` part, I got only an image with a white background. What is the goal of such division? And, why does it show the image properly when done and doesn't show the image properly if you directly show the read image without the division by max?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
I/max(I(:))
```

just normalises the pixel values to the range 0..1.0. It does this by dividing all pixel values by the max value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The case is that I have a gray scale image where the minimum value is `77` and the maximum value is `113`. Why if I don't normalize I don't get the expected output?

Comment: If you pass `double` values to `imshow` they need to be in the range 0 .. 1 - see @Nick's answer for more details.

Comment: If we have the value `77` for instance, doesn't double simply set it to `77.0`? What exactly does `double` mean in this context?

Comment: Yes, `double` converts integer pixel value `77` to double precision floating point value `77.0`. This then gets scaled to a value in the range 0 .. 1.0 when you divide by the max pixel value.

Comment: It does, and normalizing would set it (divided by 113) to `0.6814`

Comment: When I checked the `double` image, it had the normal pixel values (i.e; 77). @Paul R mentions that in order to show a double image, it has to be in the range 0-1. But. since the matrix of the double image has the normal values, why don't they show unless normalized? Thanks

Comment: `I` is not actually *modified* - it's just normalised "on the fly" when it is passed to `imshow` - if you want to normalise it for more than just passing it to `imshow` then you could say `I=I/max(I(:));` and then just pass `I` to `imshow`.

Answer (score 2):

`max(I(:))` seems to be a normalize step

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/imshow.html%20%22documentation) follows that imshow needs a input matrix having values between 0 and 1.0

> imshow(I) displays the image I in a Handle Graphics® figure, where I
>   is a grayscale, RGB (truecolor), or binary image. For binary images,
>   imshow displays pixels with the value 0 (zero) as black and 1 as
>   white.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The case is that I have a gray scale image where the minimum value is `77` and the maximum value is `113`. Why if I don't normalize I don't get the expected output?

Comment: Because your values are not in the 0..1.0 range, so you need to correct for that. The value 113 will be displayed as white, and 0 will be black. You can also use `imshow(I, [low high])', here you can set the range.

Answer (score 0):

`I` is a 2D or 3D matrix (depends on grayscale or color). `I(:)` is the vector where all values of the matrix are written in a column, just like they are arranged in the memory; you could do by [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) as well. Please read more about the colon-operator in [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), it is an absolut basic concept of Matlab.

`max` gives you the maximum over a vector, i.e. `max(I(:))` gives you the maximum value over the whole image.

It is an unwritten law that the range of an image starts at 0. Therefore you can map the values of the image to `[0,1]` by dividing it by `max(I(:))`. In Matlab it is done like that: `myMatrix/myScalar`.

So `I/max(I(:))` gives you the image with values in `[0,1]`, what is required for double-images that you want to show with `imshow`.

Please note:

(1) You can write `imshow(I,[])` instead which will show you the image with values stretched to `[0,1]` (in difference to your version the minimum is mapped to 0 as well).

(2) In my view you should map the values of an image for visualization only in exceptional cases like you do. It can give you wrong impression of the image (e.g. a very dark image will be visualized as full contrast image). Try to devide by maximum of the original value range (often 255, 4095 or 65535). Example:

```
img = imread('some12bit.png');
img = double(img);
img = img / 4095; % [0,4095] -> [0,1]
imshow(img);
```

(3) Without mapping the image to `[0,1]` all values `> 1` will be interpreted as `1`. That's why your image is shown as a white image without mapping it to `[0,1]` before.